# pass array to web api AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I can't pass array from angularJS to web api action in mvc4.

My $resource is:

```
adminApp.factory('presentation', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/presentation/:id', { id: '@id' },
        {
            update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id' } },
            save: { method: 'POST', params: { model1: '@model1' } },
            remove: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' } }
        }

    );
}]);
```

AngularJS code for pass array of data to save it(**presentationItemList** that I want to pass):

```
$scope.savePresentation = function() {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {

            if ($scope.presentation.Id != undefined && $scope.presentation.Id > 0) {
                $scope.presentation.$update({ id: $scope.presentation.Id });
            } else {
                $scope.presentation.$save({ model1: presentationItemList });
            }
        } else {
            $scope.addFormValidationAlert($scope.form);
        }
    };
```

My Api action that call after **save** action in AngularJS:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(PresentationItemModel model, List<PresentationElementInfoModel> model1)
    {
        var item = Mapper.Map<PresentationItemModel, Presentation>(model);

        model.Id = GetActionResultData(ServiceDataProvider.PresentationCrudService.SaveOrUpdate(item));
        if (model.Id.MoreThanZero())
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<PresentationItemModel>(model,
                                                                 new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            };
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

I get an error in firebug: **"Can't bind multiple parameters ('model' and 'model1') to the request's content"**

This code work fine,if I dont't pass array **presentationItemList** from angular and don't map it in **model1** param of web api action.

Please, help me!

Comment: How is your resource injected? Can you show us your entire controller? A quick look in your function let me with this doubts: (1) Your `presentationItemList` isn't defined in your `$scope`?; (2) If you are using your resource, why you call `$scope.presentation.$save`? That `$save`, if you are using your resource, should be just `save`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$save` method `params` parameter is used to bind to the url template or gets passed as querystring. Doing `{ model1: presentationItemList }` may not work as i think the behaviour would be to serialize the presentationItemList and add it the url.

On Angular side you should add the presentationItemList as a sub property on the $scope.presenation as

`$scope.presenation.items=presentationItemList`

and do a `$save` without passing parameter.

The problem with WebAPI is that it cannot take multiple parameters for POST. So the list should be part of the `PresentationItemModel` and things would work property.

If you cannot change the server model, then the approach should be to first save the parent, get the id of parent and then make a second call to save the child list.

Comment: You are true about two params in POST action!